# Microsoft Kinect Sensor Custom Width and Height (3840*2160) C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, kinect

I want to show camera on big 3840 * 2160 inch screen but currently its showing  kinect sensor on 1920 * 1080 only. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: you just can stretch it on screen and set main window maximize

Comment: I am using 4 screens with Eyefinity display as one screen and the problem is kinect sensor is showing on first screen only

Comment: so you have to change type of showing windows for your monitors how can show a window full screen on all of monitors it will be ok